# Tomcat Build Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

The projet work fine in tomcat localhost but when I upload it in a remote tomcat I get this bug :/ , I have the jar that contain the ImageReaderFactory class in classpath, I didn't understand what can be the problem, 
I cleared the /tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost folder but always the same bug : **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

```
07-Oct-2019 23:06:25.584 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-267] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [UploadServlet] in context with path [/MyServer] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dcm4che3/imageio/codec/ImageReaderFactory
    at org.dcm4che3.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.setMetadata(DicomImageReader.java:794)
    at org.dcm4che3.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.readMetadata(DicomImageReader.java:713)
    at org.dcm4che3.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.read(DicomImageReader.java:452)
    at com.project.dicomserver.UploadServlet.getFrameIcon(UploadServlet.java:86)
    ....
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5sEH.png)

Comment: What is the location of the jar?

Comment: the location of the jar is /WebContent⁩/⁨WEB-INF⁩/⁨lib⁩

Comment: And is WebContent inside webapps?

Comment: yes, /Desktop/myApp/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: That does not seem right.. can you upload an image of the directory structure of your tomcat server? Also which version of tomcat is this?

Comment: `UploadServlet.getFrameIcon` why is your servlet trying to load a frame icon?

Comment: @aksappy I added an image of the directory

Comment: Okay, You are running this on eclipse.. that explains.. can you open the war file that you generated and see whether all the jars in your classpath are in the war file?

Comment: Yes, i already verified that, all jars are in /webcontent/web-inf/lib of the war file

Comment: @aksappy have you any suggestions plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of things that could be go wrong in your specific case. So answering with the best of my knowledge. Make amendments, by adding as much details as possible, to the question and we can help you further.

Every application in tomcat needs to have a specific folder structure. The folder structure is documented [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html). In short, war files must be deployed into `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/` directory.

So if your application is "`myapp`", then there must be a `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/myapp` directory.

Inside `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/myapp` directory, we need to have `WEB-INF`. Not `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/myapp/WebContent/WEB-INF`, but `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF` ! And the case matters.

If this is not how your application is deployed into a vanilla tomcat, it will not work properly. Read the official [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)

Now about your development environment, see whether your eclipse configurations have been modified. The `Export As War` options can be modified at multiple locations and all of them can have impact on the war file you have generated. When in doubt, I look at this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war)

> Use a build tool like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/). These tools bring standards for compiling, archiving, testing and deploying applications and makes you worry less on environment related issues.

Comment: thank you @aksappy for your reply, my app is under `/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF` ,  but I'm not sure about $CATALINA_BASE path,

Comment: I think I found the problem, when I upload the war, i get this in log: 

`09-Oct-2019 12:18:04.598 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-328] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Failed to scan [file:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/dcm4che-imageio-opencv-5.18.1.jar] from classloader hierarchy
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/tomcat/lib/dcm4che-imageio-opencv-5.18.1.jar (No such file or directory)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...`

the same thing with all jars, but my tomcat is in `home/deploy/it/tomcat/` and not `/usr/local/tomcat/`, can be that the problem?

Comment: How did you install tomcat and how are you starting it

Comment: I have no idea how it was installed, the person who installed it is on vacation, and I am stuck :/

Comment: How are you starting the server? Can you start from the bin folder just outside where you placed your war?

Comment: (the server is already started)
I run this command
`/tomcat/bin$ ./startup.sh`
`Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program`

Comment: Okay.. you need to setup your tomcat as well! Look for some tutorial for your specific version and distribution.

Comment: how about this bug : 

` java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1894)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
 at org.opencv.osgi.OpenCVNativeLoader.init(OpenCVNativeLoader.java:17)`


do you have any idea about it please? (I don't have this bug in local, just in remote server)